# what's the meaning of CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION()?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was reading the source code of opencv and I don't understand the function 
`CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION()` called by other function. The `CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION()` function usually appears at the start of the other function body. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/bf4c5bef7fa254e996f31d3e3d7f81ce63716c13/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp#L538

Answer (score 9):

You can check the corresponding pull request for more information: [Implementations instrumentation framework for OpenCV performance test system](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7101).

> Instrumentation framework for OpenCV performance test system. It was
>   developed to:
>
> - track implementations execution inside OpenCV functions with call tree
>     output to test logs
> - track implementations execution time weight in the
>     pipeline
>
> Framework can be enabled with ENABLE_INSTRUMENTATION define
>   in CMake and disabled by default. In disabled state it doesn't consume
>   resources.

**Update:**

OpenCV 3.3 added the support of trace / profiling OpenCV applications for users. For more information see:

- the corresponding pull request: [Code tracing support #8766](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8766)
- the Wiki page: [Profiling OpenCV Applications](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Profiling-OpenCV-Applications)
- a sample code [application_trace.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/application_trace.cpp)